# How to grant access to populate a field with out displaying the field to the user

Tags: custom-field, edit

I need to prepopulate an Opportunity Custom field upon creation.

I use URL Hacking to pass the value from the Account to the Oppty using a new "New" button.

```
/006/e?retURL={!Account.Id}&accid={!Account.Id}&00ND0000005hajn={!Account.Payment_Terms_Partner__c}
```

All is working in that process.

Now I need that the target field will hidden from the user. So basically, I want to give a user access to set value to a field, without him viewing that field.

I tried with page layout: hidden/read only - didn't work
Field permissions - no luck.

*** **Test with Process builder** ****

Trying to do that with process builder, I get an unhandled error

> caused by element : FlowDecision.myDecision caused by: The flow failed
>   to access the value for
>   **myVariable_current.Account.Payment_Terms_Partner__c** because it hasn't
>   been set or assigned.

**Account.Payment_Terms_Partner__c** - is a formula field on the account, that takes one of two payment terms, either from the account, or the account.owner.account or defaults to: immediate

**** **Test with Flow and Process builder** ****

According to [Judi Sohn](http://judisohn.com/2015/04/06/using-salesforce-process-builder-flow-with-opportunity-contact-roles/) I tried to use a flow and a process builder

Flow: is a simple record update that gets the oppty id and the payment terms to update.

[image]

[image]

The process is just as simple, on creation, call the flow

[image]

The criteria is to fire the process when the partner_payment_terms__c is NOT null

[image]

Still, I am getting the error when creating the oppty

[image]

The error appears both for Admin and Partner license.

(I am thinking to change the workflow, and grant access to the field, but ALWAYS update it to the default value - basically the user can't change)

Any ideas?

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you leverage workflow here?

Comment: Have you thought about using a flow? That might be able to solve your problem, and it can easily be initialized from a visualforce page via the interview tag. You can also pass it parameters (such as the one you've specified). Can you give a little more data on what you're trying to accomplish beyond blocking access?

Comment: I'm pretty sure to update a field via url hack it has to be editable on the page layout, like the comments above I think you need to look at other options (workflow.flow etc)

Comment: Is that happening when you're running it as a admin or a non privileged user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion with SF support: Process builder, Workflow rules and Flows - can not update a picklist value based on a formula field (or other picklist value)

The only option is to use a text field (every of the flow, process etc, can update a text field.